# How do I comment out multi-lines in netbeans version 8.0?

Tags: netbeans

I used to be able to turn multi-line codes into a single line by clicking on the minus sign on the left of the code and add // to comment out a multi-line code. Now when I do it, the code just gets deleted…

What do I do?

Comment: Works fine for me still. Are you sure you have deselected the code block before you type //  Otherwise you are overwriting it. You could also use the shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+C after you have clicked the minus sign to comment out that block.

Comment: I did have the code block selected… but I went back in and I tried to comment a block of php code by clicking on the minus sign and then deselect the block code and just added two backlashes before the first letter of the code..what happens is the first line of the block gets commented and the block opens with the rest of the block not commented. Same thing happens when I use the short cut… is because it is a php code?? And how does netbeans know that a particular block of code is a block and thus give you the minus box to click??

Answer (score 38):

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: And the opposite, to uncomment a commented-out region, select the lines and use CTRL + SHIFT + C.

Answer (score 17):

Simply Select all lines and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

- for **Window** comment and un comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- for **Mac** comment and un comment: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Select all the Lines and press the following keys correspondingly -

**Windows** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

**Macintosh** - <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I am using emacs as my netbean editor and ctrl+/ nor ctrl+shift+c worked.
I found what does work by going to keyboard mapping and searching for
comment.  There I found ctrl+c ctrl+c adds and alt+0 ctrl+c ctrl+c removes
comments from pre-selected code.  The key to this answer is:  check your own
keyboard mapping. (tool-option-keymap).

Answer (score 1):

To out comment on my Mac from Germany, I only have to press: cmd + shift + c
On Windows, it is ctrl + shift + c

Answer (score 0):

for windows: `ctrl` + `c`

for Mac: `⌘ Cmd` + `⇧ Shift` + `c`